# Migration from C++ to C#, related to pointers

Tags: c#, c++, pointers

I am C++ programmer, and I am working on a migration project where I need to convert C++ code to C# and I have little knowledge on C#.

The C++ code that I am migrating is having lot of pointer operations such as

```
Hdr->States = (DspState*)baseAddress; // Converting the buffer to other type.
```

My question is,

1. Is there any harm if I do unsafe programming in C# as long as I keep track of memory properly.
2. Or is there any other way in C# to handle these kind of pointer operations (sometimes double pointers).

Comment: If you're going to be refactoring your code I would take baby steps to accomplishing the goal. Start with a C++/CLI wrapper for the code that you intend to rewrite. Begin to capture the business logic into C# and just rewrite the code where it is necessary.

Comment: @Romoku: I am not refactoring the code. Its complete migration of the project which was developed in C++ to C#.

Comment: If the C++ code is allocating untyped buffers that are later used as specific types, perhaps you should rework the code to create the buffers with the exact type (class) they need to be at the time they are allocated. Is this template code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are porting a project from C++ to C# your first goal should be to stay completely withing the *safe* world of managed code.
Just because you were using pointers in your C++ code does not mean you have to do the same in C#. Unsafe code in C# should actually be your very last option and only be necessary in very special situations.

The code in your example could like like this in C# and does not need any pointers or unsafe operations whatsoever.

```
BaseAddress baseAddress = ...
Hdr->States = (DspState)baseAddress;
```

or as type-checked cast operation

```
Hdr->States = baseAddress as DspState;
```

C# / .NET uses references all the time, which are in a way like pointers but without the dangers of pointer arithmetics.

Answer (score 0):

C# authorize the unsafe context in order to allow the use of pointer so if your code was working in c++ it should do fine in c# but depending on whatt you want to do it is not necessary the best solution.
For exemple if you use a c++ library which exist in c# you may have to use pointer in c++ but in c# references are used instead.
If the kind of operation that you show in post are the only one you use, i think you shouldn't use an unsafe context juste to reference and dereference pointer and you should do a full conversino of your code.